# how can I mock the request of a function when I try to test a method

Tags: sinon

//user.dal

I have this two methods in user.dal, and I am trying to test the method1, but its have a request inside called function1 (I want to fake the result of this) I am using a sinon.stub

```
export async function function1(id) {
      try {
        const result1 = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
        return result1;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('invalid user');
      }
    }

export async function method1(id, date) {
  const request1 = await function1(id); // this is not faking its results
  const request2 = await function2(request1); // this need to fake the results also
  return request2;
}
```

//user.test

```
describe.only('get all information ', () => {
    const id = '5c842bd3cf058d36711c6a9e';
    const user = {
      _id: '5c76f49e6df2131fe23a100a',
    };
    const date = '2019-03-09';
    let spyFunction1;
    beforeEach(async () => {
      spyFunction1 = sinon.stub(userDal, 'function1').returns('this is my result');
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
      await userModel.deleteOne({ _id: id });
      spyFunction1.restore();
    });

    it('Should get.', async () => {
      const result = await userDal.function1(id);
      console.log('this is working well', result);

      const badResult = await userDal.method1(id, date);
      console.log('-->>>', badResult); // when its call to method 1, its calling to the method and not using the mock that I impemented before
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`import` doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

> The static `import` statement is used to import bindings which are exported by another module.

So when you do this:

```js
import * as userDal from './user.dal';
```

the result is that `userDal` contains bindings to everything exported by the `user.dal` module.

---

Then when you do this:

```js
sinon.stub(userDal, 'function1').returns('this is my result');
```

the `function1` binding is replaced by a `stub` which returns `'this is my result'`.

In other words, the **module export for `function1` has been replaced by the stub**.

---

So when this line runs:

```js
const result = await userDal.function1(id);
```

it is calling the *module export* for `function1` (which has been stubbed) so the result is `'this is my result'`.

---

On the other hand, when this line runs:

```js
const badResult = await userDal.method1(id, date);
```

it enters `method1` which then runs this line:

```js
const request1 = await function1(id); // this is not faking its results
```

which is not calling the *module export* for `function1`, **it is calling `function1` directly**.

---

In order to be able to stub `function1` and `function2` within `method1` you must call their **module exports** instead of calling them directly.

---

For a `Node.js` module the pattern looks like this:

```js
const function1 = async function (id) { /* ... */ }
const function2 = async function (id) { /* ... */ }

const method1 = async function (id, date) {
  const request1 = await exports.function1(id);  // call the module export
  const request2 = await exports.function2(request1);  // call the module export
  return request2;
}

exports.function1 = function1;
exports.function2 = function2;
exports.method1 = method1;
```

---

For an ES6 module the pattern is similar.  Note that ["ES6 modules support cyclic dependencies automatically"](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_cyclic-dependencies-in-ecmascript-6) so we can `import` a module *back into itself* to get access to the module exports:

```js
import * as userDal from 'user.dal';  // import module into itself

export async function function1(id) { /* ... */ }
export async function function2(id) { /* ... */ }

export async function method1(id, date) {
  const request1 = await userDal.function1(id);  // call the module export
  const request2 = await userDal.function2(request1);  // call the module export
  return request2;
}
```

If you follow this pattern and call the **module exports** for `function1` and `function2` from within `method1` then when you replace the *module exports* for those two functions with stubs, the stubs will get called when you call `method1`.

Comment: Yeap thank you for you advice, I moved to another file and use Import and export, and it is working well. Thank you so very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make the method signature like this: `method1(id, date, function1, function2)`. You'd essentially be passing in the function1 as a parameter. Then in your test, you can instead pass in a mocked function or stub to be able to test it.

```
export async function function1(id) {
      try {
        const result1 = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
        return result1;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('invalid user');
      }
    }

export async function method1(id, date, function1, function2) {
  const request1 = await function1(id); 
  const request2 = await function2(request1);
  return request2;
}
```